# Kernel Source -- In which file is brk() defined

Tags: linux, kernel, brk

I would like to know in kernel source version >= 2.6 where `brk` is defined. That is which c file contains its definition? `grep` is not revealing much. Also `sbrk` is implemented in glibc correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `mmap.c`. Look for:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(brk, unsigned long, brk)
```

The manual page says:

> On Linux, sbrk() is implemented as a library function that uses the
>   brk() system call, and does some internal bookkeeping so that it can
>   return the old break value.